# Inequalities with absolute value question

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Solve: $ 5< \left\vert\dfrac{x+10}{x-10}\right\vert<6$

attempt at a solution:

Dividing into two:

$5<\left\vert \dfrac{x+10}{x-10}\right\vert  $     And  $\left\vert \dfrac{x+10}{x-10}\right\vert<6  $

For first we solve: 
 $ \dfrac{x+10}{x-10}<-5  $  or $ \dfrac{x+10}{x-10} >5  $  which yields $( -∞,15)$

For Second:

$  -6<\dfrac{x+10}{x-10}  $  and $ \dfrac{x+10}{x-10} <6  $  which yields $(14, ∞)$

intersecting the two we get $(14,15)$

This solution was deemed wrong by the text book. 
Is there any other way of solving this? Is there a mistake in this method of solution?

Comment: The first one is surely not correctly solved. Can you add details about how you did it?

Comment: As a sidenote, solving $25<\left(\frac{x+10}{x-10}\right)^2<36$ is easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that $10$ isn't even in the domain of the given function, your solution to the first inequality cannot be correct. Without actually seeing the details, though, it's hard to say what went wrong.

As an alternative, note that $\frac{x+10}{x-10}>0$ for $x>10$ and for $x<-10,$ and $\frac{x+10}{x-10}<0$ for $-10<x<10$. It's far simpler, then, to proceed casewise.

If $x<-10$, the following are equivalent: $$5<\left|\frac{x+10}{x-10}\right|<6\\5<\frac{x+10}{x-10}<6\\5(x-10)>x+10>6(x-10)\\5x-50>x+10>6x-60,$$ but $5x-50>x+10$ yields $x>15,$ so we can rule out all $x<-10$ as solutions to the inequality.

If $x>10,$ the following are equivalent: $$5<\left|\frac{x+10}{x-10}\right|<6\\5<\frac{x+10}{x-10}<6\\5(x-10)<x+10<6(x-10)\\5x-50<x+10<6x-60.$$ $5x-50<x+10$ yields $x<15,$ while $x+10<6x-60$ yields $14<x,$ so all $x$ with $14<x<15$ will be solutions to the inequality.

If $-10<x<10,$ the following are equivalent: $$5<\left|\frac{x+10}{x-10}\right|<6\\-5>\frac{x+10}{x-10}>-6\\-5(x-10)<x+10<-6(x-10)\\-5x+50<x+10<-6x+60.$$ $-5x+50<x+10$ yields $\frac{20}3<x,$ while $x+10<-6x+60$ yields $x<\frac{50}7,$ so all $x$ with $\frac{20}3<x<\frac{50}7$ will be solutions to the inequality.

Hence, the solution set is $$\left(\frac{20}3,\frac{50}7\right)\cup(14,15).$$

Comment: Somehow I only get the  $(14,15)$ part of solution...

Comment: I've added another answer to show how you can reach the solution with your method, for comparison. See what you think.

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, we can certainly work through it using your method of solution. I will focus first on $$\left|\frac{x+10}{x-10}\right|<6.$$

Now, to solve $-6<\frac{x+10}{x-10},$ we will of course wish to multiply by $x-10$ and solve the resulting linear inequality. Here's the catch: *we don't know whether* $x-10$ *is positive or negative!* Both cases must be considered. If $x-10$ is negative, then the following are equivalent: $$-6<\frac{x+10}{x-10}\\-6x+60>x+10\\50>7x\\\frac{50}7>x.$$ If $x-10$ is positive, then the following are equivalent: $$-6<\frac{x+10}{x-10}\\-6x+60<x+10\\50<7x\\\frac{50}7<x$$ However, this is misleading. In order for $x-10$ to be positive, we require $x>10>\frac{50}7,$ so we didn't actually learn anything new, there. Hence, the solution set to $-6<\frac{x+10}{x-10}$ is $$\left(-\infty,\frac{50}7\right)\cup(10,\infty).\tag{1}$$ We run into similar complications when solving $\frac{x+10}{x-10}<6$. If $x-10$ is positive, the following are equivalent: $$\frac{x+10}{x-10}<6\\x+10<6x-60\\70<5x\\14<x$$ If $x-10$ is negative, then $\frac{x+10}{x-10}<6$ yields $14>x,$ but this is again misleading, since for $x-10$ to be negative, we need $x<10<14.$ Hence, the solution set of $\frac{x+10}{x-10}<6$ is $$(-\infty,10)\cup(14,\infty).\tag{2}$$ Therefore, the intersection of $(1)$ and $(2)$ is the solution set to $\left|\frac{x+10}{x-10}\right|<6,$ that is $$\left(-\infty,\frac{50}7\right)\cup(14,\infty).\tag{3}$$

Now, let's solve $5<\left|\frac{x+10}{x-10}\right|.$ If $x-10$ is positive, then so is $x+10,$ so $\frac{x+10}{x-10}>0>-5.$ Hence, we can only have $\frac{x+10}{x-10}<-5$ if $x-10$ is negative, so the following are equivalent: $$\frac{x+10}{x-10}<-5\\x+10>-5x+50\\6x>40\\x>\frac{20}3$$ This is also misleading, though, since for $x-10$ to be negative, we need $x<10.$ Hence, the solution set to $\frac{x+10}{x-10}<-5$ is $$\left(\frac{20}3,10\right).\tag{4}$$ If $x-10$ is negative, the following are equivalent: $$\frac{x+10}{x-10}>5\\x+10<5x-50\\60<4x\\15<x$$ That is impossible, though, since for $x-10$ to be negative, we need $x<10<15.$ If $x-10$ is positive, the following are equivalent:$$\frac{x+10}{x-10}>5\\x+10>5x-50\\60>4x\\15>x$$ Since we require $x>10$ in order for $x-10$ to be positive, then the solution set to $\frac{x+10}{x-10}>5$ is $$(10,15).\tag{5}$$ Therefore, the solution set to $5<\left|\frac{x+10}{x-10}\right|$ is the union of $(4)$ and $(5),$ that is $$\left(\frac{20}3,10\right)\cup(10,15).\tag{6}$$ The intersection of $(3)$ and $(6)$ is thus the desired solution set, and is the same as was found with the casewise approach.

---

**Upshot**: There's nothing technically wrong with the method you were using, but it takes more work, there's a great deal more to keep in mind, and there is a lot more room for error. I strongly recommend the casewise approach, instead.

Comment: Many thanks for your heartily replay and attention in this problem...You're the man!

Answer (score 2):

Distinguish three cases:

(i) $\quad x<-10$:

Here the given equation amounts to
$$5<{-x-10\over10-x}<6,$$
or $50-5x<-x-10<60-6x$. In particular $4x>60$, which is incompatible with $x<-10$. So there are no solutions $x<-10$. Note that $x=-10$ isn't a solution either.

(ii) $\quad-10<x<10$:

Here the given equation amounts to
$$5<{x+10\over10-x}<6,$$
or $50-5x<x+10<60-6x$, which is equivalent with ${20\over3}<x<{50\over7}$. Note that these $x$ indeed lie in the interval $\ ]{-10},10[\ $. For $x=10$ the given condition makes no sense.

(iii) $\quad x>10$:

Here the given equation amounts to
$$5<{x+10\over x-10}<6,$$
or $5x-50<x+10<6x-60$, which is equivalent with $14<x<15$. These $x$ are indeed $>10$.

It follows that within ${\mathbb R}$ the solution set of the given equation is
$$\bigl]{20\over3},{50\over7}\bigr[\ \ \cup \ \ ]14,15[\ \ ,$$
but the equation is meaningless at $x=10$.